# How do I stop ssh from offering other keys?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I have some server `dev.example.com` and in its authorized_keys file I have my `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` key. I also have an `~/.ssh/my_test.pub` key.

My `~/.ssh/config` specifies that for `dev.example.com` it should use `id_rsa` as one would normally want.

However, I'm trying to test to make sure that `my_test` will only allow the access that I want. So I tried to pass in the `-i`dentity file:

```
$ ssh -v -i /Users/wwerner/.ssh/my_test example
.
.
.
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/wwerner/.ssh/id_rsa
```

And it logs in. Crap.

Okay, so maybe it's an issue with me using `example` instead of the FQDN:

```
$ ssh -v -i /Users/wwerner/.ssh/my_test dev.example.com
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/wwerner/.ssh/id_rsa
```

And it logs in. Maybe I need my username?

```
$ ssh -v -i /Users/wwerner/.ssh/my_test myusername@dev.example.com
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/wwerner/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Okay... so now I cast my net even further. Maybe the config file is what's causing it:

```
$ ssh -v -F /dev/null -i /Users/wwerner/.ssh/my_test myusername@dev.example.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /dev/null
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/wwerner/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Argh! So maybe if I use -o as well?

```
$ ssh -v -F /dev/null -o IdentityFile=/dev/null -i /Users/wwerner/.ssh/my_test myusername@dev.example.com
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/wwerner/.ssh/id_rsa
```

What am I doing wrong? What setting do I have to specify so that ssh will *not* offer up my `id_rsa`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the directive `IdentitiesOnly` in conjunction with the `IdentityFile` directive.

On the commandline you can use:

```
ssh -v -o "IdentitiesOnly=yes" -i /Users/wwerner/.ssh/my_test dev.example.com
```

As alternative you can set the directive in your `.ssh/config` file at the section for your host.

See `man ssh_config` for details

Comment: Thanks!  User chrishiestand offered some helpful context on this option at https://superuser.com/a/436015/58805